# How can I pass by value a nested Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I want to clone an object that has more objects inside of it, without accidentally modifying the first object. To try to explain this more easily, I will try an example with an object that has only one property first

```
obj1 = {test : "hey"}
obj2 = obj1
obj2.test = "hi"
```

This will modify the first obj too, which is something that I don't want. After searching a bit I realized I have to do this instead:

```
obj1 = {test : "hey"}
obj2 = Object.Assign({},obj1)
obj2.test = "hi"
```

Now obj1 seems to be unmodified. Yay! But here is my problem, I have an object that has nested objects as properties. Imagine that it looks like this:

```
obj1 = {test : {moretest : "hey"}}
obj2 = Object.Assign({},obj1)
obj2.test.moretest = "hi"
```

This creates the problem that if I Object.Assign the initial obj1 to obj2, the nested objects will still be passed by reference (so if I change obj2.test.moretest, then obj1.test.moretest **will also change**, even though I used Object.Assign!)

How can I clone an object by value along with all the nested objects inside of it?

Comment: you can check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#browser_compatibility

Comment: looks like JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object_or_array)) does the job here! Thanks :)

Comment: This may be more robust [clone object w/o the limitations of JSON.parse](http://dassur.ma/things/deep-copy)

Comment: Great information there, thank you :)